# Firefox Bottom Horizontal Scrollbar Not working

Tags: firefox, scrollbar

I have this issue on Firefox 53.0 (64-bit). Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

[image: Bottom Borizontal Scoolbar]

Is just BOTTOM Horizontal Scrollbar. Any other Horizontal Scrollbar inside web pages works but not this one.

Anyone has this issue?

Comment: Is this question related to the contents of the page? If it's a Firefox issue behavior in Ubuntu I think you're question might be better migrated to https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What you mean about "not working"? the orange line is not moving to the right when you drag it with your mouse? What happen if you press Ctrl+Right Arrow?

Comment: @SebastianFerrari Yes. I cannot drag ... and on hover is doing nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry @Florin, but I couldn't replicate your issue. I've tried with the same versions but in a virtual machine. Does it happen with all websites or with only some of them?

Comment: it seams latest version of Firefox 58.0 (64-bit) fixed the issue ... awesome ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Try one of these two things:

1. Try using Shift + Scroll. On most web browsers, by using these two commands at the same time it will scroll you horizontally across the webpage. Be careful though, because if you scroll the wrong way or too fast you might end up going to the previous webpage instead.
2. Zoom out so you see the entire width of the page, and then use your curser and arrow keys to zoom into the right side of the screen which used to be hidden.